# Drawing a progress bar while running a function for a desired time in bash script

Tags: bash, progress-bar, iperf

I want to add progress bar while giving the percentage of the function to be completed such as [===>         ] 20% completed. For example, I have a code which uses `iperf` and I give the time duration that I want.

```
function Throughput_test()
{
    iperf -c $otherIP -u -b 1000m -t 10 -i1 
 # Here is where I want to add the progress bar. 
 # This function takes 10seconds and I want to 
 # see the progress bar.
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/11592583/1426891

Comment: It supposes to work. But the example with pv that I want is not clear to implement.

Answer (score 0):

`pv` and `dialog` (or `xdialog` or `zenity`) may be useful here.

- [`pv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) sits in the middle of a pipe-based operation, counting the data that goes through the pipe and drawing a progress bar based on the expected number of lines/characters of transferred data.
- [`dialog`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) is a fairly-comprehensive GUI tool for shell scripts, with `xdialog` and `zenity` as X and Gnome equivalents. Sending well-formatted data into `stdin` allows you to create an updatable progress bar, but sending the right format can be tricky.
- You can write your own custom dialog using `printf`, `echo -n`, and so forth; that's just a matter of outputting the characters one at a time using your own math. You can send the cursor to an already-drawn part of the screen using `tput` or by echoing `\r` (carriage return, as opposed to newline).

Comment: Hello, can you give me a quick demonstration of pv. What I can do is not completely working. As an example I am trying:
`my_function 10 | pv > /dev/null`. _my_function_  part gets input 10 to run 10 seconds and I want to print pv session accordingly. Thanks